# Run illustrator extendscript through automator applescript or bash?

Tags: applescript, adobe, automator, extendscript

The following command will run the `SCRIPT_ABC.jsx` which is located on my desktop. Is there a way to take the contents of the `SCRIPT_ABC.jsx` and put the javascript extendscript exclusively inside automator so when I save it out as an application it will be included within the program?

```
 on run {input, parameters}

        tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open file "Macintosh HD:Users:NAME:Desktop:SCRIPT_ABC.jsx"

        return input
    end run
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste the entire jsx into your applescript as a text body, then use the `do javascript` command to run it. Applescript has a great benefit of being able to pass in arguments to the jsx (`do javascript myScript with arguments { textVariableHere, anotherOneHere }`) and obtain the returned result too!

## Elaborated edit:

```
set myJavascript to "
#target illustrator
function test(args){
    var docName = app.activeDocument.name;
    alert(\"Hello from Adobe JSX. Current document name is: '\" + docName + \"'\\n\" + args[0]);
    return docName;
};
test(arguments);
"
set myInputVar to "The input string here."
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set myResult to do javascript myJavascript with arguments {myInputVar}
end tell
display alert ("Returned Document Name is: '" & myResult & "'")
```

So what you see here is an example of a javascript embedded inside the applescript as a string. Lucky for me, I have AppleScript Debugger app which I paid for a long time ago and is well-worth it, and it has the "Paste as string literal" function which auto-escapes the quotes and stuff. Very helpful.

[image: Paste as String Literal]

But you can see the magic of passing in a variable to the javascript as applescript arguments which prevents a lot of issues one could have doing string-building inside applescript to put variables in.

[image: Illustrator alert box]

Although you don't have to use AppleScript arguments to put data into the jsx, as you can use the string-building mentioned above (which I do not recommend when the arguments way is available for use), the huge payoff is actually getting the returned jsx data back into the applescript. Really neat stuff.

[image: AppleScript alert box]

So there you have it, the whole enchilada! I would be curious to see if there's a comparable native way to do a similar setup with Windows and VBS + JSX combo - if anyone is aware of something like this please let me know in the comments below.
Thanks!

*PS:
The word `arguments` used in the function call of the main function of the **jsx script** is actually a **key-word used by AppleScript** and it has to be spelled out like so, otherwise it will not work.*

## More Edit:

Okay, so maybe you don't wanna paste no huge jsx into your applescript and escape all the quotes, etc.

I get it. No worries! You can do the following:

Ensure your jsx is somewhere installed along with you app (it could be binary), so save the following code which represents your jsx body as a jsx file wherever:

```
var docName = app.activeDocument.name;
    alert("Hello from Adobe JSX. Current document name is: '" + docName + "'\n" + args[0]);
    return docName;
```

And in your AppleScript you simply change the jsx portion to the following:

```
set myJavascript to "
#target illustrator
function test(args){
    #include '/Users/YourName/Wherever/myAppleScriptJsxTest.jsx'
};
test(arguments);
"
```

BOOM! Works exactly the same! Isn't that something?

Comment: could you post an example? my script is fairly large. I've been looking everywhere but cant seem to find a solution. ty

Comment: Okay, I will see about creating the rudimentary example once I get home today !

Comment: Extremely helpful! thank you!! How would I make it link to work with any computer or maybe put it inside the app? I would like it to work on any user or computer. #include'/Users/YourName/Wherever/myAppleScriptJsxTest.jsx'

Comment: To put inside the app without any extra bother, use my first example. And if you want to use a stand-alone jsx, then ship that .jsx with instructions for them to put it into a generic location - perhaps, and resort to string-building that path inside of your .app. Specifically, you have to obtain the user's path with their user-name and put it there. Maybe it could be a way to go. *However, you certainly can't put this on a Windows computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the .jsx file to the `Contents/Resources` folder of your Automator application bundle, and use a *Run AppleScript* action to get the resource

```
on run {input, parameters}     
    try 
        set thePath to path for resource "SCRIPT_ABC" extension "jsx" 
        tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open (thePath as POSIX file) 
    on error errmess 
        display dialog errmess 
    end try 

    return input 
end run
```

Note: You will need to copy the file in question again to the bundle `/Contents/Resource` folder when you recreate your application bundle since Automator creates a fresh bundle each time you save it.

Also, it may be required to close Automator/the Script Editor after you have added the file. Finally, test the resulting app and see if it launches the file in the requested app.

Comment: this came back with A for:resource can’t go after this path. The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.Automator error -212.)”

Comment: this still returns the same problem.. any ideas? I used the automator program to create this and it keeps bugging out

Comment: im getting the following error.  The variable thePath is not defined.  i also tried path to me as text and it returned as:  Can’t make alias "Macintosh HD:Users:NAME:Desktop:RUN_S.app:Contents:Resources:SCRIPT_ABC.jsx" into type POSIX file.

Comment: @Likenota I've tested it end-to-end and it works for me as described above. Have you actually copied the file into the bundle.app/Contents/Resources folder?

Comment: are you using the automator to save out the application? i have tried this countless of times without any positive result. I keep getting this error with your script posted above  The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.Automator error -212.)”

Comment: @Likenota What I did: Compose the app using Automator save it (the script shows an error, this does not matter). Add the file to the app bundle/Contents/Resources. Then, run the app.

Comment: still same results. im not entirely sure what you have different on your end but im literally setting it up exactly the way you have it. any other ideas?

Comment: If this is the case: I can only think of one difference, I have a fairly old macOS installation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the AppleScript that executes ~/script.jsx (there can be any jsx script) via Adobe Illustrator:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    do javascript "(function(){//@include '~/script.jsx'}());"
end tell
```

Or you can set Adobe Illustrator to open all jsx files by default. After that a double click on any jsx file will make Illustrator to execute the script. It works on Windows and MacOS.